# Scrape HTML Table. UWP and C#

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have the following code for scraping the following HTML table:

Code that just gets the 'Service' in the table.

```
var MobileSiteLinks = MobileDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class,'content')]//a[starts-with(@class,'service')]");

                    foreach (var a in MobileSiteLinks)
                    {
                        DestinationPlaces newPlace = new DestinationPlaces();
                        newPlace.Services = a.InnerText.Trim();
                        places4.Add(newPlace);
                    }

<table class="busexpress-clientwidgets-departures-departureboard">
<thead><tr class="rowStopName"><th colspan="3" title="briamaw" data-  lat="50.8016420087726" data-lng="-0.0475264219580729" data-bearing="">Cranleigh Avenue</th><tr>
<tr class="textHeader"><th colspan="3">text briamaw to 84268 for live times</th><tr>
 <tr class="rowHeaders"><th>service</th><th>destination</th><th>time</th><tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr class="rowServiceDeparture">
 <td class="colServiceName">27</td>
 <td class="colDestination" title="Saltdean">Saltdean</td>
<td class="colDepartureTime" data-departureTime="29/05/2017 15:04:00" title="1 mins">1 mins</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowServiceDeparture">
<td class="colServiceName">14B</td>
<td class="colDestination" title="Peacehaven">Peacehaven</td>
<td class="colDepartureTime" data-departureTime="29/05/2017 15:19:00" title="16 mins">16 mins</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowServiceDeparture">
<td class="colServiceName">12A</td>
<td class="colDestination" title="Eastbourne">Eastbourne</td>
<td class="colDepartureTime" data-departureTime="29/05/2017 15:22:00" title="19 mins">19 mins</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowServiceDeparture">
<td class="colServiceName">27</td>
<td class="colDestination" title="Saltdean">Saltdean</td>
<td class="colDepartureTime" data-departureTime="29/05/2017 15:23:00" title="20 mins">20 mins</td>
</tr>
```

I am aware that SelectNodes is not supported in UWP apps now. How do I get the same information using the new format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am aware that SelectNodes is not supported in UWP apps now.

UWP app does have  `SelectNodes` relative methods. If you save the above table as a XML file, you can use the [`Xml​Document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument) class, it contains the [`SelectNodes(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument#Windows_Data_Xml_Dom_XmlDocument_SelectNodes_System_String_) method. For example:

```
 Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument doc;
 StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Onetable.xml"));
 Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlLoadSettings loadSettings = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlLoadSettings();
 doc = await Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(storageFile, loadSettings);
 var xpath = "//tr[@class='rowServiceDeparture']"; 
 var MobileSiteLinks = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

More details you can reference [XmlDocument official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument).

Your code snippet looks like you are using the `HtmlAgilityPack` package. If above content just save as HTML format, you also can use `HtmlAgilityPack` in UWP app, it also contain the `SelectNodes` method as you showed above. Pay attention to use [HtmlAgilityPack for .NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore/) which is supported in UWP.

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("url");
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var result = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
HtmlDocument MobileDocument = new HtmlDocument();
MobileDocument.LoadHtml(result);
var nodes = MobileDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='rowServiceDeparture']");
```

Comment: Thanks. Used the HtmlAgilityPack for net and this worked with my existing code!